# How do you access the number in a simple array to then divide them by a certain number

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create an array where I have the numbers 13 and 31, I want to find the largest number in the array that is divisible by 13 and the largest number that is divisible by 31. These numbers need to be integers. How can I do this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question03 {
    public static int[] array;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
            int tempArray[] = {39, 93, 26, 62, 13, 31};
            array = tempArray;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++)
            System.out.println(tempArray[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share code which you're trying out so far? Sorry but straightaway asking for solutions without showing off any efforts is considered bad here.

Comment: Please take a look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should share you code

Comment: There are many possible way to resolve this problem. If you use Java 8 or + you can use stream, filter and max functions to resolve this problem

Comment: Déjà Vu (almost): https://stackoverflow.com/q/66460366/15244370

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop with the remainder operator (`%`).

```
int max13 = -1, max31 = -1;
for(int x: array){
   if(x % 13 == 0 && x > max13) max13 = x;
   if(x % 31 == 0 && x > max31) max31 = x;
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/YjLj0r)

`Stream`s can also be used.

```
int max13 = Arrays.stream(array).filter(x->x%13==0).max()
        .orElse(-1);//-1 if there is no element divisible by 13
int max31 = Arrays.stream(array).filter(x->x%31==0).max()
        .orElse(-1);
```

Comment: what int shoudl I add to my system.println(); to show the values?

Comment: @leastbasket590 `System.out.println(max13);System.out.println(max31);`

Comment: @leastbasket590 See the [demo](https://ideone.com/YjLj0r).

Comment: @leastbasket590 Does my answer work for you?